# Integers $n$ such that $n^2$ is of the form $3k+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, gcd-and-lcm

Find all integer $n$ such that $n^2$ is of the form $$3k+2.$$

In observing I find that it has no integer solution, but I can't solve it mathematically. Any hint regarding this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $n$ as $3m+r$ with $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $r\in\{0,1,2\}$

Comment: m(3m+2)+$r^2+r$=$n^2$.how I say it is not of form 3k+2?

Comment: Please explain it sir?

Comment: $(3m+r)^2=9m^2+6mr+r^2=3(3m^2+2mr)+r^2$, but none of the possible values of $r$ give $r^2=2$

Answer (score 7):

$$n^2 = 3k+2$$

Solving for k:

$$k = \frac{n^2 - 2}{3}$$

For this to be an integer,

$$n^2 - 2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$
$$n * n \equiv 2 \mod 3$$

The fundamental property of multiplication in modular arithmetic states:

$$(a\ \%\ m) * (b\ \%\ m) \equiv (ab\ \%\ m) \mod m$$

where % is the modulo operator. Therefore:

$$n * n \equiv 2 \equiv (n\ \% \ 3)^2 \mod 3$$

$n\ \%\ 3$ can be either $0$, $1$, or $2$, so $(n\ \%\ 3)^2$ can be either $0$, $1$, or $4$ respectively. None of these are $2$ (mod $3$), so $k$ can never be an integer, regardless of what you choose n to be.

Answer (score 2):

Any perfect square , say $n^2$,  when divided by $3$ leaves either $0$ or $1$ as remainder. ( Check yourself by taking $n$ as $3m$, $3m+1$ or $3m+2$ ).
Here $(3k+2)$ when divided by $3$, leaves $2$ as remainder.
Hence $(3k+2)$ cannot be a perfect square for any integer $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the point of posting this as an answer to a three year old question with an accepted answer?